# XPages get Value selected from combo box

Tags: combobox, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I want to display the selected value from the comboBox into a label.

```
<xp:label id="label4">

    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var componenta = Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv");

if (componenta == "")
{ return "void";}

if (componenta !="")
{ return "My value is "+componenta}}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:label>
```

The label is on a panel, and I did a partial refresh to the respective panel.
 My comboBox is binded to a data element.

label4 is always `void`. Why? 
Thank you,

Florin

Answer (score 0):

Try `Contr.getValue("txt_tipcontractcv")` (assuming that Contr is your datasource).

Answer (score 0):

I changed code into:

```
var componenta = getComponent("combo").getValue();

if ((componenta == null) || (null == componenta))
{ return "void";}

else if ((componenta != null) || (null != componenta))
{ return "My value is "+componenta}
```

and now it returns : My value is
It seems that componenta is an empty string. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the value selected is not sent to the server.
Could you give us the code for combobox, and panel with label. It will give us clear idea for the cause

1. Are you using partial execution mode?
2. Is combo box bind to data source value="Contr.txt_tipcontractcv"?

You may also code the label as below, if that suits

```
<xp:label id="label4" value="Contr.txt_tipcontractcv" />
```